# Running a script to check disk usage creates a new file. why?

Tags: linux, shell

When I excecute the script.sh file which has content as follows

```
USE=`df -h "/scratch/" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed s/%//g`
if [ $USE>30 ]; then
   echo "The limit has exceeded"
else
   echo "The limit is not exceeded"
fi
```

It creates a new file 40 in the directory where it is executed. Why is this happening?

Comment: It should be creating a file named `30`, not `40`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if [ $USE>30 ]; then
```

`>30` means to redirect the output of the command to a file named `30` (not `40`). You need to quote the `>` character to prevent its special meaning. Also, the `test` command requires each argument to be separated:

```
if [ $USE '>' 30 ]; then
```

However, `>` is for alphanumeric comparison. For numeric comparisons you need to use `-gt:

```
if [ $USE -gt 30 ]; then
```